# Invalid input error in Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Invalid input error in Neo4j cypher query

```
MATCH (n:CriticalAsset) where n.name starts with 'Highly Confidential Data Type' RETURN n
```

I am getting invalid input error.Fields and attributes are correct.
[image]

Below picture, will gives you an idea about the node
[image]

Appreciate your help to identify the mistake.

Error message for your reference:

```
Invalid input ' ': expected an identifier character, '.', whitespace, '(', node labels or rel types, '[', '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, USE GRAPH, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 38 (offset: 37))
"MATCH (n:CriticalAssets) where n.name contains 'Highly Confidential Data Type' RETURN n"
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if the `name` is within back ticks like , 

`MATCH (n:CriticalAsset) where n.\`name\` starts with 'Highly Confidential Data Type' RETURN n`

Comment: Great, i have tried this and works for me. Thank you @aldrin

Comment: Cool! Will convert my comment to an answer

Comment: Using backticks should only be necessary if a property name contains characters that are not normally allowed in a name. Also, the error says the problem was with ' ', not the `name` property name. It is possible that your query had a non-space character that happens to look like a space character (at offset 37 from the start of your query) after `n.name`. Things like that can happen when you copy a query from elsewhere else (like a web site, or Word or PDF file).

Answer (score 1):

Sometime the issue is related to indentation. Have you tried to input the cypher query manually, which might helps to solve as your syntax and query seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Put `name` within backticks

```
MATCH (n:CriticalAsset) where n.`name` starts with 'Highly Confidential Data Type' RETURN n
```

Backticks are used to ignore special characters and spaces in node labels and properties. It is likely that `name` has some special character or a space. It might be worth checking whether you intend `name` to be that way